# Ошибка MySQL, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, mysqli

Что не так с этой строкой?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products (id, name, text) VALUES ('$row[\"id\"]', '$row[\"name\"]', '$row[\"text\"]')";
```

выдает ошибку

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\test.php on line 69
```

Comment: Ну начать можно с того, что у вас здесь SQL-инъекция

Comment: @andreymal, знаю, это локальный скрипт, интернет он никогда не увидит

Comment: Ну значит вы должны знать, что в запрос могут инъецироваться кривые данные и тем самым вызвать подобную ошибку

Comment: "Доктор, я ходить не могу" "у тебя из ноги гвоздь торчит" "да я знаю, но ничего не болит, поэтому и так сойдет"